# Confusing 'monitor' tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

We have the tags [monitoring](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) (x11) and [monitor](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) (x3). Quite obviously, the latter leads to some confusion: while some take it as a synonym to `monitoring`, others take it to refer to a computer monitor.

I already re-tagged the ones referring to `monitoring` (process), which leaves those referring to a `monitor` (device).

**Suggestion:** Renaming `monitor` to `external-monitor`.

Hopefully this should be enough to avoid the confusion. As tag selection involves some "auto-complete" feature, people should be able to distinguish the two. Optionally, we could of course make `monitor` a synonym to... what? I'd better refrain from that, as it would re-introduce above described confusion. So, only rename the tag?

Answer (score 1):

We already had [external-display](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-display) so I merged [monitor](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitor) into it and created an [external-monitor](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/external-monitor) synonym.

I think [monitoring](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) needs some work though, it's too vague — there are lots of unrelated things that you can monitor.  If everything is referring to process monitoring, perhaps we should rename the tag to [process-monitor](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/process-monitor)?

Comment: Maybe I was a little ambiguous in my reference here: I didn't mean everything is process-orientated there, what I meant was "hardware" (monitor=display) versus the "process of monitoring" (not restricted to the monitoring of processes). And with just 11 questions being tagged `monitoring`, I don't think we currently need more specific tags for this. Thanx for the other merge -- I didn't know we already had `external-display`...

Comment: @Izzy No, I wasn't confused by what you said, but I do think we need to split `monitoring` or perhaps remove it entirely.

Comment: If you remove it, I guess it will re-appear. I guess in a while we may have use for differentiation like cpu-monitoring, data-monitoring, process-monitoring, ressource-monitoring, etc. Currently it is hard to say which of those make most sense, IMHO. I will meanwhile add a tag wiki to make clear what it is about.

Comment: Frankly, I think "monitoring" isn't a very useful tag. Using it for three or four different types of "monitoring" won't clarify anything. If you want to ask a question about monitoring your CPU, tag it with [tag:cpu]. Data monitoring seems to be covered under [tag:data-monitor] _and_ [tag:data-traffic].